# how to convert Observable<List<A>>to Flowable<A>

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I tried to convert `Observable<List<A>>` to `Flowable<A>` in RxJava, however it doesn't work.

```
return  resource.flatMap(
    new Function<Observable<List<Product>>, List<Product>>() {
      @Override
      public List<Product> apply(Observable<List<Product>> products) throws Exception {
        return (List<Product>) products;
      }
    }).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `flatMapIterable`:

```java
return resource.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
               .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```